# Can i join three tables in snappy data

Tags: join, snappydata

I need to perform colocate join on category and subscriber tables

And i also need to perform colocate join on category and likes tables
can i denfine colocate_with option as more than one table

Answer (score 1):

Define one leader region and colocate all tables with it. So by transitivity, everyone will be colocated.
e.g. table A is colocated with table B, table C is colocated with table B => Hence Table C is also colocated with table A